# Orbits of the dynamical system $\dot r=-r\log r$, $\dot\varphi=2r\sin^2\left(\varphi/2\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> I have a question regarding this specific 2-dimensional DE: $$\dot r=-r\log r\\\dot\varphi=2r\sin^2\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)$$ where $r> 0$ and $\varphi\in [0,\infty)$ (yes, $2\pi$ would do it as well).

Now, I want to see how the stationary point $(1,0)$ is attractive. It is easy to see that $\dot\varphi>0$ at all times $t$ so all solutions constantly rotate until hitting a stationary point. 
For starting values left of $(1,0)$ (so $r<1$) we also see that $\dot r>0$ and for starting values right of $(1,0)$ we have $\dot r<0$. So let's say we start at some point in the first quadrant left-above of $(1,0)$ (for example $\frac{1}{2}(1,1)$). Then the solution moves into the direction of the unit circle while also doing a spiral since $\dot\varphi >0$. But how does this work? How can $\varphi$ and $r$ both increase at all times when I start left-above the stationary point $(1,0)$? How does it ever hit $(1,0)$ without decreasing again?

I hope, I could make my problem clear enough. If not, I can provide a sketch of what I mean. Maybe also my question can be answered if someone provides a sketch of the trajectory starting at the mentioned point $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: The $r$ equation is exactly solvable: $r(t)=e^{e^{-t+C}}.$ Also, wouldn't $r$ have to be strictly positive?

Comment: Yes, I edited it.

Comment: But I think I got it now. If we start at $\frac{1}{2}(1,1)$, the trajectory has to hit the unit circle before $\varphi$ hits $\pi/2$, so that we have $r\equiv 1$ and the rest of the way will be on the unit circle.

Comment: Yep. The entire unit circle will be attractive because of the sign of $\dot{r}$ relative to $r=1$. And as long as you are "close enough" to $\varphi=0$, $\varphi$ will increase until you get to the next stationary point, where it will stop.

Comment: But then for some starting values the trajectory should hit, for example, $(0,\pi)$ first which is also a stationary point so it should get stuck there. This would mean that in total $(1,0)$ is not attractive, right?

Comment: But $(0,\pi)$ is not in the domain of your DE, since $r$ is undefined there.

Comment: True, I meant $(1,\pi)$.

Comment: Well, and that point's on the unit circle, right?

Comment: Yes, but if the trajectory gets there first it will stay there. So $(1,0)$ is not attractive, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $0<r<1$, we have $\dot{r}>0$, which means $r$ will increase. If $1<r$, then $\dot{r}<0$, so $r$ will decrease. This implies that $r=1$ is attractive, period. No matter where the system starts (other than at the undefined origin), $r=1$ is attractive.

The exact solution of the $r$ equation is $r(t)=e^{e^{-t+C}}$ or $r(t)=e^{A\,e^{-t}},$ where $A=e^C$. This is always positive.

Turning our attention to the $\varphi$ equation, we see that $\dot{\varphi}\ge 0$ for all $r,\varphi$ (and hence for all time). The stationary points for $\varphi$ are:
$$\frac{\varphi}{2}=n\pi\quad\implies\quad \varphi=2n\pi.$$
Therefore, we say that wherever $\varphi$ starts, it will increase until the next integer multiple of $2\pi$, which it will approach asymptotically without exceeding. In the polar system, therefore, there is really only one unique attractor point: $(1,0)$.

Comment: You wrote: "wherever $\varphi$ starts, it will increase until the next integer multiple of 2π, and then stop." How it is possible when we have the **uniqueness** of the initial value problem?

Comment: It's going to approach that point asymptotically. The point is, $\varphi$ cannot *cross over* an integer multiple of $2\pi.$

Comment: @user539887 "and then stop" might be slightly misleading, what the phrase really means is that $t\mapsto\varphi(t)$ is increasing with limit "the next integer multiple of 2π" (hence the angle $\varphi$ always "moves").

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more mathematically correct and less pedagogically sound, as is usually the case.

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see how the new version is "less pedagogically sound" (there might be some traces of automatic thinking in your last comment).

Comment: Most of the time, in my experience, a simple term used mostly correctly, but maybe not precisely, is easier for most students to understand than several complex terms used precisely.

Comment: The dichotomy has some allure, as most general principles, true or false, have, but I fail to see how it applies to the present case. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did: Well, looks like we'll just have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: As you wish. Adding some arguments in support of the statements you see fit to throw on the page would be a different, albeit not inferior, approach.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

From

$$
\dot r=-r\log r\rightarrow -\frac{dr}{r\log r} = dt
$$

or

$$
\log r = C_0 e^{-t}\to r = e^{C_0 e^{-t}}
$$

or also

$$
\frac{dr}{d\varphi} = -\frac{\log r}{2\sin^2(\frac{\varphi}{2})}
$$

This is a separable DE and can be arranged as

$$
-\frac{dr}{\log r} = \frac{d\varphi}{2\sin^2(\frac{\varphi}{2})}
$$

etc.

After a convenient change of variables,

$$
x = r\cos\varphi\\
y = r\sin\varphi\\
\dot x = \cos\varphi \dot r - r\sin\varphi \dot\varphi\\
\dot y = \sin\varphi \dot r + r\cos\varphi \dot \varphi
$$

and

$$
\dot r = -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\\
\dot \varphi = 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin^2\left(\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac yx)}{2}\right)
$$

and after a little elaboration we have  the stream plot

[image]

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: ...Maybe also my question can be answered if someone provides a sketch of the trajectory starting at the mentioned point... At $(\frac 12,\frac 12)$ begins an unstable orbit.

Comment: What is your change of variables? What are the axis labels on the stream plot?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Please. See note attached.

Comment: This is not the streamplot. Note that $[r=1,0<\varphi<2\pi]$ is a trajectory of the dynamical system.

Comment: @Did   Are you sure of that? Show your hypothetical stream plot then. Corrected the exponent for $\sin^2(\varphi/2)$

Comment: ?? Yes I am sure, no need for a plot for such a basic reasoning: at $r=1$, $\dot r=0$ hence $r=1$ forever, then $\dot\varphi=2\sin^2(\varphi/2)$ hence $\dot\varphi>0$ for every $0<\varphi<2\pi$, end of the proof.

Comment: @Did   You have reason. I had made a stupid mistake. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Your new plot is much more convincing...